# How to populate a Rails dropdown menu with a json array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, jquery

I have an Ant show page that displays detailed information about various types of ants. On that page there are two drop downs, one for environment: [indoor, outdoor], and one for diet: [sugar, fat, protein].

When you select a param from each it renders out a product page depending on the params. However, some combinations result in nil, like a carpenter ant doesn't have a product associated with indoor, sugar.

I'm trying to get the dropdowns to populate based on whether or not a combination is nil. If someone selects indoor I'd like sugar to not appear in the next drop down if that combo doesn't exist.

So far I have I have two methods creating json arrays for only the available items:

```
def food_sources
  food_sources = Ant.find(params[:ant_id]).product_recommendations.where(environment: params[:environment]).map(&:diet)
  render json: food_sources.to_json
end

def environments
  environments = Ant.find(params[:ant_id]).product_recommendations.where(diet: params[:diet]).map(&:environment)
  render json: environments.to_json
end
```

For example, if input

```
http://localhost:3000/ants/27/food_sources?environment=indoor
```

into the browser it returns

```
["sugar","protein"]
```

bc for the ant with an id of 27 only has two options for outdoor indoor diets, instead of the possible three.

My question is how do I pass this array into my rails dropdown if someone picked the above combination?

**EDIT**

```
= form_tag ant_product_recommendations_path(@ant.id), id: 'select_box',  method: :get do |form|
  %h3 What food source are they currently feeding on?
  = select_tag :environment, options_for_select([["Select One"], "Indoor", "Outdoor"])
  %h3 
    Locate the nest by following the ants back from their food source.
    %br
    Where is the nest located?
  = select_tag :diet, options_for_select([["Select One"], "Sugar", "Fat", "Protein"])
  = submit_tag "Find Solutions", class: 'submit button' 
  = link_to 'Go Back', '/', class: 'go_back'
```

Comment: Why json and not an ajax call?

Comment: No reason. This was my first theory. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Json should be used with an Ajax call in my opinion

Comment: Is this a good or bad idea to allow open queries like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me like you want to dynamically populate the dropdown box, which would lend itself to an ajax call, like this:

```
$('#select_box').on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/controller/action",
        type: 'get',
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function (data) {
        change_select(data);
    });
});

function change_select(data) {
    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    var options = [];
    json.each(function (key, index) {
        options.push({text: index, value: key});
    });
    $("#select_box").replaceOptions(options);
};
```

This will allow you to specify the options of the dropdown, and you can use the controller in this way:

```
  @food_sources = Ant.find(params[:ant_id]).product_recommendations.where(environment: params[:environment]).map(&:diet)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @food_sources }
  end
```

Comment: This code will be full of holes, but I hope it shows you what you can do to achieve your goal :)

Comment: Thanks for your post! What would the view look like. I'll post my form haml to my original post.

Comment: Okay, no need for my edit. It seems your current form is okay (if it contains the drop-down options you'd like to show people?). The appending of the dynamic options should be done by javascript, but I guess the big question would be how to make it so that the user can bring the selection back to the original. I could go into chat about it if you wanted?

Comment: I'd love to talk to you about it. if you have a moment. I apologize I was away from my desk.

Comment: Sorry! I lost the link.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39380/discussion-between-reknirt-and-rich-peck)

Comment: Just add to one info, if you're sending request to an action in the same controller, you don't need preceding `/` before url.